# Jinja2 : declaring and saving array

Tags: arrays, variables, jinja2

I am new to Jinja2 and I was forced to use it for a custom web application. I want to declare an array and save values to it. Can someone suggest me where I am going wrong?

```
    {%- for row in doc.other_charges -%}
    {%- if not row.included_in_print_rate -%}
            {% set data[i]=row.description %}
            {% i++ %}
            {% set data[i]=row.get_formatted("tax_amount", doc) %}
            {% i++ %}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Your `data` variable is declared inside the `for` loop and not available to the outer scope.
2. There is no `++` operator in Python.

But the main issue is that, you should actually have *business logic* inside your views and *presentation* in your templates. Even if you find a workaround to make your example work, you should still move your logic to the view that generates the context variables to be consumed by your template. Your templates must be simple enough to be left alone when a business requirement change.